# Remove unwanted text in logo detection- Image Processing, Computer vision

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, graphical-logo

I am trying to detect logo in invoices. Though I am able to get some results but not sufficient enough to process. While detecting logos, Unwanted text is also getting detected.
The following is from actual invoice:-[original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3BOv.jpg)

and the following results I am getting [Image after operations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj4Wn.jpg)

I am using the`following code which I have written:-

```
gray=cv2.imread("Image",0)
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray,180,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
kernel_logo = np.ones((10,10),np.uint8)
closing_logo = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh1,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel_logo, 
iterations = 1)
n=3
noise_removed_logo = cv2.medianBlur(closing_logo, n)

eroded_logo = cv2.erode(noise_removed_logo,kernel_logo, iterations = 8)
dilated_logo=cv2.dilate(eroded_logo,kernel_logo, iterations=3)
```

Could you please help me what changes should I make to remove noise from my documented image. I am new to Computer Vision

Few more sample:- [Original document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vog3O.jpg)
The result I am getting:- [Result after operations on document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzrqu.jpg)

Comment: Is the logo on images always on the upper right corner?

Comment: No, It can be anywhere, no fixed location.

Comment: first of all you should define what makes a logo a logo. this is a very complex problem. if you know which logos you're looking for it's not a big deal. Otherwise I wouldn't even try.

Comment: My document consists of all three types, symbolic, wordmark and combinational. Any approach you can suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Mohd Anas Khan .

Your approch to define logo is too simple so it couldn't work. If you want a product-level approach, use some machine learning or deep learning. If you want just some toys, then a simple countours finder with fixed rules should work.

For example, in the following approach i defined "logo" as "the contour which has biggest area". You'll need more rules later, so good luck.

```
    import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('contours_1.jpg')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

rect_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 5))
threshed = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, rect_kernel)
cv2.imwrite("contours_1_thres.jpg", threshed)

im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshed,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

ws = []
hs = []
areas = []
for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    print("w: {}, h: {}, area: {}".format(w, h, area))
    ws.append(w)
    hs.append(h)
    areas.append(area)

max_idx = np.argmax(areas)

cv2.drawContours(im, [contours[max_idx]], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
# cv2.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

cv2.imwrite("contours_1_test.jpg", im)
```

The output images are as follow : (The detected logo is covered in green box )

[image: first image output]

[image: second image output]

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.
Yeah I have tried multiple things with contours, most of them work but still I don't think this approach is suitable for product level. I am planning to start working with deep learning but the problem is data, Can you suggest how can I craete a proper dataset for detecting logos in documents?

Comment: i don't know your problem's scope so i can't tell you how to create a proper dataset. But from the two images about, i think a small dataset with few hundreds of sample can be enough.You can have sample from google image search or flickr.

Comment: I have invoices of different formats. I am trying to recognize the logo in the document. Which dataset and which approach should I use? I can't find any properly labeled dataset.

Comment: I don't have detail about your data so I can not say which approach is good, which is bad. About the dataset for training, in my experience, if some similar dataset is available, you're luchky. If there isn't any similar dataset, you have to create it by yourself.